# removing duplicate groups of n lines

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, sorting

Is there a way to find unique n lines group, and sorting them as well? for example the following file content:

```
GPO: Microsoft Office Settings v2021.06
Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\16.0\access\security\trusted locations\location20\description
Value:       74, 0, 38, 0, 74, 0, 32, 0, 71, 0, 101, 0, 110, 0, 101, 0, 114, 0, 97, 0, 108, 0, 32, 0, 84, 0, 114, 0, 117, 0, 115, 0, 116, 0, 101, 0, 100, 0, 32, 0, 76, 0, 111, 0, 99, 0, 97, 0, 116, 0, 105, 0, 111, 0, 110, 0, 0, 0
State:       Enabled
GPO: Google Chrome Settings v2022.02
Folder Id: Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\CookiesAllowedForUrls\144
Value:       91, 0, 42, 0, 46, 0, 93, 0, 104, 0, 108, 0, 100, 0, 46, 0, 99, 0, 104, 0, 0, 0
State:       Enabled
GPO: Internet Explorer Policy Settings
Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\DisableCachingOfSSLPages
Value:       0, 0, 0, 0
State:       Enabled
GPO: Google Chrome Settings v2022.02
Folder Id: Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\CookiesAllowedForUrls\38
Value:       91, 0, 42, 0, 46, 0, 93, 0, 100, 0, 111, 0, 99, 0, 117, 0, 115, 0, 105, 0, 103, 0, 110, 0, 46, 0, 110, 0, 101, 0, 116, 0, 0, 0
State:       Enabled
GPO: AnyConnect Settings
Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\QoS\Cisco AnyConnect\
Value:       67, 0, 105, 0, 115, 0, 99, 0, 111, 0, 74, 0, 97, 0, 98, 0, 98, 0, 101, 0, 114, 0, 46, 0, 101, 0, 120, 0, 101, 0, 0, 0
State:       Enabled
GPO: AnyConnect Settings
Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\QoS\Cisco AnyConnect\
Value:       67, 0, 105, 0, 115, 0, 99, 0, 111, 0, 74, 0, 97, 0, 98, 0, 98, 0, 101, 0, 114, 0, 46, 0, 101, 0, 120, 0, 101, 0, 0, 0
State:       Enabled
```

n=4, The GPO policy `AnyConnect Settings` appears multiple times, and has duplicate attributes (Folder Id, Value, State), after processing the file, it should look like this:

```
GPO: AnyConnect Settings
Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\QoS\Cisco AnyConnect\
Value:       67, 0, 105, 0, 115, 0, 99, 0, 111, 0, 74, 0, 97, 0, 98, 0, 98, 0, 101, 0, 114, 0, 46, 0, 101, 0, 120, 0, 101, 0, 0, 0
State:       Enabled
GPO: Google Chrome Settings v2022.02
Folder Id: Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\CookiesAllowedForUrls\38
Value:       91, 0, 42, 0, 46, 0, 93, 0, 100, 0, 111, 0, 99, 0, 117, 0, 115, 0, 105, 0, 103, 0, 110, 0, 46, 0, 110, 0, 101, 0, 116, 0, 0, 0
State:       Enabled
GPO: Google Chrome Settings v2022.02
Folder Id: Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\CookiesAllowedForUrls\144
Value:       91, 0, 42, 0, 46, 0, 93, 0, 104, 0, 108, 0, 100, 0, 46, 0, 99, 0, 104, 0, 0, 0
State:       Enabled
GPO: Internet Explorer Policy Settings
Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\DisableCachingOfSSLPages
Value:       0, 0, 0, 0
State:       Enabled
GPO: Microsoft Office Settings v2021.06
Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\16.0\access\security\trusted locations\location20\description
Value:       74, 0, 38, 0, 74, 0, 32, 0, 71, 0, 101, 0, 110, 0, 101, 0, 114, 0, 97, 0, 108, 0, 32, 0, 84, 0, 114, 0, 117, 0, 115, 0, 116, 0, 101, 0, 100, 0, 32, 0, 76, 0, 111, 0, 99, 0, 97, 0, 116, 0, 105, 0, 111, 0, 110, 0, 0, 0
State:       Enabled
```

How can I programatically perform this.

Edit: Below is what I have right now:

```
import json
import re

GPOs = []
regexs = ['GPO:', 'Folder Id:', 'Value:', 'State:']

with open("administrative-templates-after.txt", mode="r") as after_template:
    lines = after_template.readlines()
    entry = []
    for index in range(0, len(lines) - 1):
        for regex in regexs:
            if re.search(regex,lines[index]):
                entry.append("%s %s" % (regex, lines[index].replace(regex, "").strip()))
        if len(entry) == 4 or ( len(entry) == 3 and re.search('State:',entry[len(entry)-1])):
            GPOs.append(entry)
            entry = []
    GPOs = list(dict.fromkeys(list(map(tuple, GPOs))))


with open("after_templates_unique.txt", "w") as fp:
    json.dump(GPOs, fp, indent=2)
```

It works for now, first it groups the lines into a list of arrays, and removes the duplicate lines, but I feel like it can be optimized as right now it works by brute force.

Once I am able to find a better approach I will try and sort these groups.

Comment: Parse the lines, write a comperator to check if they have the same  GPO policy, Ignore duplicates and sort the them. There exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: I did parse the lines into arrays and remove the duplicates, but I feel like my solution was a brute force and inefficient, edited the question with my current code, once I'm able to optimize it I will will try and sort it.